# Get data from array with a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array with data from an API.

Here is the data from the API.

```
[
  {
    "id": "litecoin",
    "name": "Litecoin",
    "symbol": "LTC",
    "rank": "6",
    "price_usd": "48.5624",
    "price_btc": "0.0128526",
    "24h_volume_usd": "198794000.0",
    "market_cap_usd": "2576800216.0",
    "available_supply": "53061632.0",
    "total_supply": "53061632.0",
    "percent_change_1h": "-1.98",
    "percent_change_24h": "6.07",
    "percent_change_7d": "-0.51",
    "last_updated": "1506172141",
    "price_eur": "40.637987568",
    "24h_volume_eur": "166354795.08",
    "market_cap_eur": "2156317957.0"
  }
]
```

I am trying to get price_eur.
I know I can do this with

```
data.price_eur
```

The thing is eur can change to any other currency.
So if I want to get USD is use

```
data.price_usd
```

But the currency will be variable.
So I want to make the text after 'price_' variable.

I have tried something and have no succes yet.
Here is what I have tried.

```
inputCrypto = 'eur';        
var priceCURCrypto = 'price_' + inputCrypto;
var priceCUR = data[0].priceCURCrypto;
```

Can someone tell how to use a variable when looking through an array.

Comment: Instead of answering the same thing for the zillionth time, the answerers here should just vote to close this as a duplicate, which is clearly the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[[] notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)** to access the properties which name is in the variable. It will evaluate the expression inside the `[]` and use the result as the property name.

```
inputCrypto = 'eur';        
var priceCURCrypto = 'price_' + inputCrypto;
var priceCUR = data[0][priceCURCrypto];
```

**Examples**

```js
const obj = { nameA: 'NameA', nameB: 'NameB' };
const name = 'name'
const propName = name + 'A';

// Value of the propName is 'nameA', get the property with name 'nameA'
console.log(obj[propName]);
// Use string concatenation
console.log(obj[name + 'B']);
```

Answer (score 2):

With dot notation you can't do this, since what comes after the dot is considered a *literal* property name.

But you can with square-bracket notation, which takes the property name as a built string, which means you can concatenate with variables and expressions.

```
foo.bar; //looks for the property @bar
foo[bar] //looks for the property *whose name is stored* in the variable @bar
```

So in your case:

```
data[0][priceCURCrypto];
```

[Here's more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) on dot vs. square-bracket syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Use brackets

```
var priceCUR = data[0][priceCURCrypto];
```